# LDTP implementation for GUI testing Qt-app

Tags: c#, gui, юнит-тесты, qt5

При попытке приаттачится к приложению MyApp:

```
Ldtp.Ldtp qapp = new Ldtp.Ldtp("MyApp_title", "localhost", "4118", true);
```

возникает ошибка, ссылающаяся на QTCore.dll и сырец accessible.cpp.
Происходит это не только при запуске программы, с помощью которой я хочу потестить MyApp, но и временами) Случайно) Проблема появилась после установки **CobraWinLDTP-4.0.0**. Может кто-нибудь подсказать, в чем дело ?
UPD_0: скрин ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы бы привели **точный** текст ошибки.

Comment: Добавил скрин ошибки, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: Окей, это уже интереснее. Вы запускаете код под отладчиком? Если да, нажмите Retry и посмотрите stack trace (и запостите его в вопрос). Если нет, сначала запустите под отладчиком и посмотрите, воспроизводится ли проблема.